# SXA SearchService does not take more than 100 characters

Tags: sxa-search

I have created a custom `SearchService.cs` class in `Sitecore SXA 10.2`. There is a function that I've overridden i.e ContentPredicate.

```
protected override Expression<Func<ContentPage, bool>> ContentPredicate(string content){
   }
```

The `content parameter` does not take more than 100 characters, after replacing special characters in the search phrase with space.

Can anyone help here?